# defaultPrevented check in custom event

Tags: javascript, events

When emitting a custom event with Javascript, the `defaultPrevented` property is always false. Here is a short example that shows this behaviour:

```
var event = new CustomEvent("my-event", {detail: "something"});

document.addEventListener("my-event", function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    console.log(ev.detail);
});

document.dispatchEvent(event); // => "something" from console.log above
console.log(event.defaultPrevented); // => false
```

There is a link in MDN for `CustomEvent.initCustomEvent()` that has an argument `cancelable` (which I'm guessing is the problem here), but the method is deprecated. How can I check if `preventDefault` was called in a custom event?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second argument for the CustomEvent constructor accepts an object with the following properties:

- bubbles - Boolean indicating if the event should buble
- cancelable - Boolean indicating if the event is cancelable (here is the problem I had)
- detail - Any custom data you want to pass along with the event.

In the example above, just add `cancelable` and it gives the correct output:

```
var event = new CustomEvent("my-event", {detail: "something", cancelable: true});

document.addEventListener("my-event", function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    console.log(ev.detail);
});

document.dispatchEvent(event); // => "something" from console.log above
console.log(event.defaultPrevented); // => true
```